# How to map StateFlow values and pass it to view via databinding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, kotlin-stateflow

I have a `StateFlow` that I want to use with Android data binding. As values in the flow I use a sealed type:

```kotlin
data class State(
    val idState: IdState
) : UiState

sealed class IdState {
    object NotAssigned : IdState()
    data class Assigned(val id: Id) : IdState()
}

@JvmInline
value class Id(val value: String)
```

I want to use it in the view like so:

```xml
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            ...
            android:hint="@string/provide_client_id"
            android:text="@{viewModel.idText}">
```

So in the view model I have:

```kotlin
// uiState can be StateFlow or MutableStateFlow of UiState
val idText = uiState.map { state ->
    when (val idState = state.idState) {
        is UserIdState.Assigned -> idState.id.value
        UserIdState.NotAssigned -> "Not set"
    }
}
```

The problem occurs when I start the application:

```
Cannot find a setter for <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout android:text> that accepts parameter type 'kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow<java.lang.String>'
```

The problem of course is with the `map` oparator which changes type from `StateFlow` to `Flow` which then cannot be used in Android data binding. Is there a way to map `StateFlow` values without converting it to `Flow`? I know that there is a `stateIn` operator of `Flow`, but I'm not quite sure if that is indented (`StateFlow` -> `Flow` -> `StateFlow`) and how to start it with `viewModelScope` while passing it to the view through ViewModel variable.